# Using web socket to transmit data between servers

Tags: node.js, websocket

I need to synchronize some of data immediately between some servers with main one.

So I think the best and easiest way is using WebSocket in NodeJS.I have some experienced with socket.io module,but it provide client to use in browser.I looked at [engine.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io) ,it looks like socket.io too.

Is there any library to make WebSocket connection as client with out browser?
(or any alternative safe protocol for my situation?)

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be transferring data across servers, you aren't limited to using the HTTP protocol. Instead, you can use raw TCP sockets. This is how you'd make a listen server:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  // do what you need
  socket.write();
  socket.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
```

And this is how you'd connect to it from another Node process:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8080}, function() {
  // we can send data back
  client.write();
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
  // receive data here
});
client.on('end', function() {
  // we received a FIN packet
});
```

Comment: How can I make it secure?I can use ssl in websocket easily.How to secure it and how to authenticate that only validated servers connected to the main one not any one else?

Comment: You could SSL here to, see http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html. You can create a `tls.Server` which is a subclass of `net.Server`.